# "In favor of " or "In favor for"

Tags: phrase-usage

Knowing that " in favour/favor of" is standard usage in the [sense 2](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/favour) according to Longman Dictionaries Online, I noticed also people use "in favor for." Therefore, I was wondering if the latter usage is acceptable in any way?

Comment: Can you give an example of this usage that you've seen or heard?

Comment: I can't really find any examples of "in favor for" being used, except in cases like "They voted in favor for the first time since 1994", which is really two separate phrases in which "in favor" and "for" just happen to fall next to each other.

Comment: @Stangdon - I know "in favor" is used when,especially a group of people like parliament decide and vote on an issue. This usage is also mentioned by an example on LDCEO which I gave the link. However,  in this usage the dictionary does not give an example of usage of "for". Furthermore, if you search "in favor for" ( with the apostrophes), Google suggests 390k results. Before research Google  suggests like "in favor for abortion" and I can find many results in which there is "in favor for abortion". I can be wrong. They  just happen to fall next to each other.

Comment: I do not give a specific example because I did not ask the question after seeing it on a specific website. I noticed the usage on Google results and suggestions. So I wonder why people use it and when they use it to clarify the usage.

Comment: @Mrt  most of the Google results are the usage stangdon mentions, "X is in favor" -- meaning "has someone's approval" -- "for (something)".  These are two separate phrases that happen to be next to each other. 
 The few uses of "in favor for" instead of "in favor of" seem to be erroneous.

Comment: It seems like "in favor for" is sometimes used, but *of* is **much** more common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+favor+of%2Cin+favor+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20favor%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20favor%20for%3B%2Cc0  My advice: just use **of**; it's a much safer choice.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can usually say ***in favor for*** instead of ***in favor of*** and the sentence will more or less have the same meaning. For example:

> Parliament unanimously voted ***in favor of*** abolishing alcohol consumption.
>
> Parliament unanimously voted ***in favor for*** abolishing alcohol consumption.

***In favor of*** is much more common, but in this usage, ***for*** is very similar to ***of*** and is interchangeable. I think ***in favor of*** is preferable and sounds more natural, and there may be situations where ***in favor for*** sounds awkward. But generally speaking, I think you can say ***in favor for*** and still be grammatical.